# Change pointer to point to stack address instead of heap address

Tags: c, pointers, buffer-overflow, heap-corruption

In a `c` program I am trying to change the pointer address i.e. heap address to stack address so that I can reach return address from the stack. I am able to pass the desired address through the input.

The code is using a pointer for memory allocation in heap using malloc.

```
char* bufferPtr;
bufferPtr= (char*)malloc(strlen(arg2)+4);
```

In GDB values related to above code are `0x0804000a 0x0804b008`

```
0xbfffcf80: 0x41414141  0x0804000a  0x0804b008  0x4ef9dd66
```

What these two addresses correspond to because I need to change this pointer to point to some  address(say `0xbfffcfd0`) on stack. So which of these two values I have to touch.

I tried many possibilities but then I get the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy-sse2.S:2211
```

Comment: If you want memory on the stack, create a local (stack) variable.

Comment: I have a stack variable and I have its address as well but if I replace `0x0804b008`  with the "New Address" then I get error.  I suspect `0x0804000a`  may be causing a problem. Because `0x0804000a`   corresponds to `char* bufferPtr;`  and `0x0804b008`  is the actual address in heap.  So if I am changing this address then  I also need to change `0x0804000a` , But I don't know with what value should I replace it with

Comment: What did you try when you got the segmentation fault? A little more code would be helpful. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to point to stack location, you don't need to allocate memory for it. For example

```
int myfunction(void)
{
    char buf_on_stack[32];
    char *ptr_to_buf_on_stack;

    ptr_to_buf_on_stack = buf_on_stack;
    myotherfunction(buf_on_stack);
}

char *global_ptr;
void myotherfunction(char *buf_on_caller_stack)
{
    global_ptr = buf_on_caller_stack;
}
```

will have both *global_ptr* and *ptr_to_buf_on_stack* pointing to a stack allocated variable (*buf_on_stack* in this example)

Now if you want the caller's address, where that resides on the stack is architecture dependent. But gcc provides for some builtins that allow you to access it in case you're using gcc as the compiler. See here for details: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocated with `malloc()` is typically allocated on the heap. There isn't really a way to make a pointer you get from `malloc()` point to the stack. You could add a sufficiently large offset to reach the stack though.

Comment: The problem that I am facing is that memory is allocated at runtime, I forgot to mention in the code, which I have edited now, another 4 bytes are kept extra for memory allocation, so in this way I am not able to reach the stack even If I pass a large length argument.

Comment: @user5708039 Isn't it lucky that this bug is much harder to exploit than you thought? I don't think you can smash the stack with these constraints. You could try to see if any interesting values reside in memory after the buffer and overwrite these, but I do not want to help you exploit a program.

Comment: Can you help me to get an idea why 2 pointers are generated, in actual I have used malloc only once.